# aria-hidden=true give no effect in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have add aria-hidden to the search button in my web app but nothing changes in ui as i change it to false. What is aria-hidden actually mean.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{'search'| i18n}}</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARIA means "Accessable Rich Internet Application". `aria-hidden` does not affect visibility in the browser like the CSS property `display: none`.

Comment: Owh. Does it means that i cannot see the changes in the browser?

Comment: Not unless you use a screen reader or other accessibility technology.

Comment: actually what can i do with aria-hidden . i don't understand what is the use of aria-hidden and why its use

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh: here is the quote from bootstrap components documentation: `Modern versions of assistive technologies will announce CSS generated content, as well as specific Unicode characters. To avoid unintended and confusing output in screen readers (particularly when icons are used purely for decoration), we hide them with the aria-hidden="true" attribute.`

Answer (score 4):

aria-hidden is an attribute to hide html elements from screen readers. Screen readers are a type of software that reads web pages from a web browser for those who are blind or have poor vision (See JAWS or NVDA). Marking an element with aria-hidden means that a user who uses a screen reader to navigate a site won't be able to experience that HTML element.

It is similar to display:none; in that it makes an element not perceivable by a screen reader but is visible to a browser user.

It is dissimilar to display:none in that display:none makes an HTML element not perceivable to all users of a page.